# My PC got shutdown rapidly after 10 second or some time 1-2 mins

Tags: shutdown

When I switch on my PC, after 2-3 time press power button on my PC get ON, but after 10 or 1-2 mins it got shutdown.

When I open my case and seen that motherboard fan goes on for 10 seconds again off, again it on for 10 seconds again off.

This was happened three times then after it never. I also observe that some time it was on contentiously for 2-3 mins again it got shutdown.

I am very shocked! Why it is happening?

Comment: I doubt this is a virus issue, as 10 seconds is way before most non-rootkitted viruses have a time to act. I suggest you check your temperature gauges in the BIOS, and go over the cooling system (fans, obviously, as well as cooling paste)

Comment: how to check temperature gauges in the BIOS?

Comment: Shortly after turning on the machine, hit the key for BIOS setup (should be in the manual of the motherboard). Common BIOS keys include: Del, Esc, Or one of the F-keys

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a problem with your power supply or the power regulators on your motherboard to me.

Depending on how they fail electronic components can become very temperature sensitive, they can be fine at low temperatures but quickly become unstable as the temperature goes up during use. Leaving it for a while allows the component to cool down to a point where it is usable again.

Try replacing your PSU as the first step, make sure that you get one that is rated high enough for your computer.

Comment: Finally, I found issue of my motherboard gets heating after some time and that's why my PC shutdown. Any solution how to prevent heating or what is reason for heating?

Comment: @samir how did you find out it was overheating? The only way to prevent it is to keep it cool, if you know what specific component is overheating then you can get small heatsink kits (http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=small+heatsink) which you can use to help cool motherboard chips. Depending on the part it may be better to replace the motherboard as the overheating may have damaged it.

Comment: After some amount of time i seen that i was too hot!,I also tried with heat sink paste but still same issue happened.

Comment: What component was too hot? How did you find out? Speedfan (http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can be a good program to find out which part specifically is overheating. Often though sudden overheating is a sign of a dying component that needs to be replaced.

Comment: When to much load on processor immediately My PC got shutdown